# Python print list of sets without brackets

Tags: python, set

I have a list of sets (using Python). 
Is there a way to print this without the "set([])" stuff around it and just output the actual values they are holding?

Right now I'm getting somthing like this for each item in the list

```
 set(['blah', 'blahh' blahhh')]
```

And I want it to look more like this

```
blah,blahh,blahhh
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of output you want?

Comment: you could just loop through the elements of the set and print each element seperately

Comment: What about `list(s)`, or does that have too many brackets still?

Answer (score 18):

Lots of ways, but the one that occurred to me first is:

```
s = set([0,1])
", ".join(str(e) for e in s)
```

Convert everything in the set to a string, and join them together with commas. Obviously your preference for display may vary, but you can happily pass this to `print`. Should work in python 2 and python 3.

For list of sets:

```
l = [{0,1}, {2,3}]
for s in l:
    print(", ".join(str(e) for e in s))
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you want a string representation of the elements in your set. In that case, this should work:

```
s = set([1,2,3])
print " ".join(str(x) for x in s)
```

However, this is dependent on the elements of s having a `__str__` method, so keep that in mind when printing out elements in your set.

Comment: will work bad if set as 1 item

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your list of sets is called `set_list`, you can use the following code

```
for s in set_list:
    print ', '.join(str(item) for item in s)
```

If `set_list` is equal to `[{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}]`, then the output will be

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
```