# Output doubled and out of order

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using Python to write a simple Hadoop program.

**mapper.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import numpy
from collections import OrderedDict

for line in sys.stdin:
        test = OrderedDict([('1', [11, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]), ('2', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 29, 28, 18, 12, 11, 11, 10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4])])
        for f in test:
                print numpy.asarray(test[f])
```

**reducer.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line,
```

**Input file**:

```
1
2
```

**Expected Output**:

```
[11  5  5  5  4  4  4  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  2  2  2  2  2  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  3  4  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0 29 28 18 12 11 11 10  9  9  9  8  8  8  6  6  6  5  5  4  4]
[11  5  5  5  4  4  4  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  2  2  2  2  2  2  0  0  0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0]
[0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  3  4  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0 29 28 18 12 11 11 10  9  9  9  8  8  8  6  6  6  5  5  4  4]
```

**Actual Output**:

```
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0]  
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0]  
 11 10  9  9  9  8  8  8  6  6  6  5  5  4  4]  
 11 10  9  9  9  8  8  8  6  6  6  5  5  4  4]  
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  3  4  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0 29 28 18 12 11 
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  3  4  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0 29 28 18 12 11 
[11  5  5  5  4  4  4  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  2  2  2  2  2  2  0  0  0  0  0 
[11  5  5  5  4  4  4  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  2  2  2  2  2  2  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is sorted as a string, and your string contains brackets. You can solve this by formatting your string as follows:

```
print ', '.join(str(item) for item in numpy.asarray(test[f]))
```

You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/python-print-array-without-brackets-in-a-single-row) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750099/python-print-list-of-sets-without-brackets?rq=1) other SO questions for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried that and it says `error: expected string, numpy.ndarray found`

Comment: The items being joined need to be a string. I edited my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still out of order, and now begins like this: `,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 0, ,,  ,  , 0, ,,  ,  , 0, ,,  ,  , 0, ,,  ,  , 1, ,,  ,  , 0, ], )`